# How to make a legend in a plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, legend

I am unable to figure out a way to get a legend of my plot. My data is a data frame consisting of 3 columns x, y and z. x and y represent the co-ordinates of a point and z is the label(0,1,2,3) that the point belongs to. Sample data :

[image]

I need to plot a scatterplot with a legend containing a colour representing a respective label.
I have plotted the scatterplot but am unable to understand how to put the legend in it.
The code I used till now is(dft is the dataframe) :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.scatter(dft['x'] , dft['y'], c=dft['z'], cmap = 'hsv')
plt.show()
```

The figure I obtained is :

[image]

I need a legend for each color.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.scatter(dft['x'] , dft['y'], c=dft['z'], cmap = 'hsv')
plt.colorbar()
```

Comment: thanks but I need a legend for every discreet colour used(4 in this case) along with the label.

Comment: Did you plot it... if there are only four colors it should give only those colors in the legend

Comment: Yes I did but hsv contains a range of colours and it gives a bar of all those colours with a numerical scale. I have to present it to someone thus I cannot show it like that.

Comment: Then put a limit on the range it shows with  plt.clim()

Comment: Suggest using a BoundaryNorm